# Automatically adjust width of div with fixed height to it's content

Tags: html, css, overflow, flexbox, fluid-layout

Normally when text content is larger than it's container it overflows in Y-direction/vertically:

```
-----------------------
|Hello hello hello hel|
|lo hello hello hello |
|hello hello hello hel|
-----------------------
 lo hello hello hello 
 hello hello
```

However in this case I want it to automatically overflow in X-direction/horizontally, while preserving and filling up the fixed height of the div. (The width should adjust accordingly, it could show a horizontal scrollbar or it should simply overflow the container horizontally.)

```
-----------------------
|Hello hello hello hel|lo hello hello
|lo hello hello hello | hello hello h
|hello hello hello hel|lo hello
-----------------------
```

Is this possible with CSS(3)/flexbox/overflow/text-wrapping? Or if not, using JavaScript?

Comment: Out of top of my mind, couldn't you achieve with the text container that has width say 150%?

Comment: The problem is that the amount of text is variable, so a fixed with like 150% wouldn't suffice.

Comment: Do you want the text to be limited at all? Like say limited by the body width? Or do you want it to go indefinitely as long as it "lasts"?

Comment: It's like white-space: nowrap, however it SHOULD wrap accordingly to the height of the div as I tried to illustrate above

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it suits you:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".container p").each(function() {
        var pwidth = $(this).width();
         $(this).width(pwidth)

        }),
     $('.container').css({"width" : "300px" }) 
});
```

Try this. This scripts gets the longest paragraph width when its parent element width is set to auto (pay attention to inital css values) Upon finishing sets the container to the 300px (or whatever you want it to be in the end).

The down side is that it doesn't get each p width separately but only the longest one.

http://jsfiddle.net/5vfm8o86/3/

Answer (score -2):

you can try it with CSS overflow-x: visible/scroll